# Wordpress plugin database creation - How to add multiple "UNIQUE KEY's" to the table on plugin activate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Ok, so I'm trying to set the team varchar to a UNIQUE KEY so that it will trigger the duplicate key function in the following statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}vote4team (team,votes) VALUES (%s,%i) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE votes = votes + %i";
```

what am I missing?

here's the create db function withing my PluginFunctions.php

```
function create_vote4team_db() {
  global $wpdb;
  global $vote4team_db_version;

  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "vote4team";
  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    team varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    votes int(11) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id),
    UNIQUE KEY team (team)

  ) $charset_collate;";

  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
  dbDelta( $sql );

  add_option( 'vote4team_db_version', $vote4team_db_version );

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_vote4team_db' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem with the help of phpmyAmin and some SQL docs. Apparently, there's a limit to how large the unique key can be. Once I changed

`team varchar(255) NOT NULL` to something smaller like `team varchar(200) NOT NULL`

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the statement would fail with a type conversion failure rather then a unique constraint failure.

In your create statement, there's a unique index called "id" with a single column "id" and a second index called "city" with a single column "team".

In the insert statement, you are attempting to update a column named "city" which probably should be "team" and your values clause has the string and integer values reversed.

Comment: ok so I changed the column name and index to team and it's still not creating the table on plugin activation. which is weird because in phpMyAdmin it works no problem. However when I remove the `UNIQUE KEY team (team)` it works.

Comment: I would try breaking the index creation out of the table creation.

Answer (score 0):

Try making id a primary key, the result will be the same as two unique keys.

I have tables in my own plugin that define a primary and a unique key, but I've never tried two unique keys. Note the two spaces between keywords PRIMARY KEY and the definition, dbdelta is a bit quirky and needs two spaces there for some reason.

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    team varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    votes int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  id (id),
    UNIQUE KEY team (team)

  ) $charset_collate;";
```

Comment: I tried switching to from `UNIQUE KEY` to `PRIMARY KEY` and copy pasted your code and still nothing. I also pasted both statements into phpMyAdmin and it worked. Is there something else that could effect the adding of this table to the database?

Comment: I also thought possibly time is a keyword so I added backticks to it and that didn't work...

Comment: Don't use back ticks, the codex specifically tells you back ticks or apostrophes around column names won't work. Have you checked the value of $wpdb->last_error after this code? That might give you some insight as to what the problem is